# Building a spatially varying kernel

Tags: matlab, image-processing

There is a binary Mask M with background pixels as 0 and foreground pixels with value 1. I've to build a kernel which will be a circular disc function, with weights summing to 1.
However, the disc radius in the kernel at every pixel location in the background will vary as a
function of the pixel location. Let `P` be any pixel location in the background, and let `dP`
be the shortest distance from P to the foreground region in the mask image M . The radius r
of the disc kernel should be spatially dependent as follows: `r = d P if d P ≤ α` , and `r = α if d P > α` ,
value of `α`  will be set manually.

How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please post some sample code to show what you have attempted so far? Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for asking a good question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice approach supposing it's acceptable to quantize the [0,α] range of the disk radius to, say, 20 possible radii:

1. Initialize the output image as a copy of the input.
2. For each possible radius:

   a. Make a mask ([a logical array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html)) based on `d P` to determine which pixels in the image use the current radius. (If none of them do, you can `continue` to skip to the next radius.)

   b. Construct the disk filter with [fspecial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html).

   c. Apply the filter with [imfilter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html), writing the result to a temporary array.

   d. Copy just the masked region to the output image: `out(mask) = filtered(mask)`.

Increasing the number of radii allows for finer quantization and better accuracy, but increase the number of convolutions that need to be computed.

An elaboration: rather than rounding to the closest radius for each output pixel, find the two closest radii, above and below, and take a weighted sum between the corresponding filtered images to interpolate for the desired radius.

If however it is not acceptable to quantize the radius, then it is necessary to loop over every pixel of the image and construct and apply the appropriate filter over its neighborhood. You can do this manually with a double for loop, or you might find [blockproc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) helpful for this.